# about asian language support question

Tags: search

I noticed that stackOverflow supports asian languages, Ej. you can have chinese name account, you can ask question in chinese, and it also supports search in chinese. (don't know if can use chinese tag).

I tried some stackoverflow clones like shapado, OSQA, AskBot etc.. they seems do not support chinese so well like Stackoverflow.

my question is, what a should I do to make sure a site have good asian language support(specially search)?
the programming? the dataa base configuration?? or what?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to ensure that you treat all text as Unicode text, and pay attention to UTF-8 encoding where appropriate (without more details from you, it's hard to be more specific). Choose a programming language, database, and search engine that all have full support for Unicode.

Comment: I'm thinking to use one of those Q&A software I mentioned before, but I wish they have good chinese support, and don't know if I can "tweak" it to make it better chinese support.

Comment: @Kossel re:chinese support in askbot - ask me if you have questions about that. I don't think there are real problems, besides, perhaps an incomplete translation. Perhaps you have difficulty configuring the site? Please ask at askbot.org. Thanks!